# Prove that the function $\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ is increasing.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the function $$\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$ is increasing for all real values of $x$.

It sounds elementary but in fact it is challenging.

Comment: Use L'Hopital's rule a few times to study this indeterminacy as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Possibly use the taylor expansion of $e^x = 1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+\dots$?

Comment: Or even just compute the derivative of this function and study its sign.

Comment: @Mark That only works for positive values of $x$, not see the argument for negative values of $x$.

Comment: I am not clear why this is true. If the function is not defined at $0$, which it is not, then you also do not have a derivative at that point. So it cannot be increasing for $x=0$. Am I just being dense?

Comment: @TheCount No you are not dense, by l'Hopital it has a limit as $x$ goes to zero, so the function can be extended to this value. As to why it is true, it began as a conjecture on my part, and after many incorrect attempts I graphed it on Wolfram and it does seem to be increasing everywhere.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus but you didn't ask about the extension with the discontinuity removed. You asked about the function itself.

Comment: @TheCount Yes that is true. Actually I have concentrated on showing increasing for positive and negative values separately, the comment by Mark above (or similar such considerations) gives it for positive values.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Not to be rude, but it might be good to mention that in the question. The function may have a removable discontinuity, but it is simply not increasing for all reals, since it is not increasing at $x=0$. But perhaps on its whole domain. I might take a whack at that.

Comment: Doing the derivative and carefully inspecting the "signs" always works for me.

Comment: I restate my original concern. The question has a false statement. The function is **not** increasing for all real $x$. No one has proved that it is, because it is not. The function is *undefined* for $x=0$ and therefore not increasing there. I am amazed no one has pushed on this point. I have edited to make the change, since all answers deal with that anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On $(0,\infty)$, we may use Taylor expansion (just as noted in the comments).

We have:

$$f'(x) = \frac{e^x(x-2) + x +2}{x^3}$$

let's show that the numerator, which we'll call $g(x)$, is $\le 0$ for $x<0$.

$$g'(x) = e^x(x-1) + 1$$

$$g''(x) = xe^x$$

Thus, $g'$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$, and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}g'(x) = 1$ and $g(0) = 0$, so $g'(x) > 0$ on $(-\infty,0)$. Therefore $g$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0)$. But $\lim_{x\to -\infty} g(x) = -\infty$ and $g(0)= 0$, therefore $g(x) < 0$ on $(-\infty,0)$, and therefore $f'(x) > 0$ on $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: I like this solution. It remains elementary, and I am kicking myself for not thinking of it.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus well I'm glad you like it. It's tempting to give up when the derivative looks that weird, but derivatives almost always get the job done if you go far enough.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus XD same feeling. The advantage of these less experienced users is their ability not to get lost down roads like us.  :'(

Comment: @SimpleArt Hahaha. Couse just cause someone is new to the site I don't assume they have less experience.

Comment: @SimpleArt first of all, your comment is rude. Second, I am by no means a "less experienced user". I have a BS degree in pure mathematics, had research experience, and worked on many advanced topics.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Well, I don't mean it like that.  But when you don't get blinded by things like my answer, well, you don't get blinded XD.  And I'm sorry if I was being rude OpenBall, I didn't mean anything.

Comment: @OpenBall By the way this also works for positive values (of course).

Answer (score 4):

Taking Mark's advice,

$$\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac12+\frac16x+\frac1{24}x^2+\dots$$

Studying monotonicity when $x>0$ is then trivial.  To tackle when $x<0$, notice that we get an alternating series with simple upper and lower bounds due to the absolute value of each term being monotone:

$$\frac12+\frac16x<\frac12+\frac16x+\frac1{24}x^2+\dots<\frac12$$

Or,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{2k-1}\frac1{(n+2)!}x^n<\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+2)!}x^n<\sum_{n=0}^{2k}\frac1{(n+2)!}x^n$$

From there, observe that for any $k$, these bounds are monotone as well as monotone wrt $k$ for large enough $k$, and so, by the squeeze theorem,  the function in interest is monotone when $x<0$

Comment: AHHH. Was so close to posting this myself. Take my +1 and get thee hence :P

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen man, this site really gets us, doesn't it?

Comment: I think that the point I don't see immediately, is why the bounds are monotone in $x$, is it because the coefficients are decreasing ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus well, for each $k$, the bounds are monotone for $f(k)<x<0$, and $f(k)\to-\infty$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus so for any $x<0$, there exists $K$ such that for all $k>K$, the bounds are monotone.  Tbh, I didn't go and calculate whether or not the bounds are actually monotone, as I believed in the math and I'm also on my phone atm.

Comment: @SimpleArt Understood, I want to nail down the argument though, a variant of the argument is to say that this function if the limit of polynomial with positive coefficients, I think this is what your answer is trying to establish. It also follows from the definition of $e^x$ as a limit of $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$. But why should these polynomial be increasing for negative values of $x$ ? When I start to think about that I get involved in complicated considerations involving the fact that the coefficients are decreasing, so either I am missing something (highly likely) or the argument is not simple.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I'll place it on the latter and think it over.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus if I may, the lower bounds appears to always be monotone.

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$ f(x)=\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} $$
and then
$$ f'(x)=\frac{e^x(x-2)+x+2}{x^2}. $$
Now we show that $f'(x)>0$ for $x<0$ or $g(x)=e^x(x-2)+x+2>0$ for $x<0$ and hence $f(x)$ is increasing for $x<0$. Note
$$ g'(x)=1+e^x(x-1)=e^x(e^{-x}+x-1)<0\text{ for }x<0$$
and hence $g(x)$ is decreasing. Therefore for $x<0$, one has $g(x)>g(0)=0$.

Comment: Isn't this more or less OpenBall's answer?

Comment: Yes, but @xpaul has a different finish instead of the second derivative. However there are some things which should be corrected, the  denominator on the derivative, but also wants to show that $g^{\prime}$ is positive, so the inequality's should be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

One can prove the following generalization:

> For all integers $k \ge 1$ is
> $$ e^x - \left(1 + x + \cdots + \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right) = x^k f_k(x) $$
> where the function
> $$ f_k(x) = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\int_0^1 e^{xu} (1-u)^{k-1} \, du $$
> is continuous and strictly increasing on $\Bbb R$.

This follows immediately from Taylor's theorem with the integral remainder:
$$
 e^x - \left(1 + x + \cdots + \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right) = \int_0^x \frac{e^t}{(k-1)!}(x-t)^{k-1} \, dt \\
 = \frac{x^{k}}{(k-1)!} \int_0^1 e^{xu} (1-u)^{k-1} \, du \, ,
$$
where we have substituted $t = xu$ in the last step.

Comment: Sorry for my comment I am trying to understand the computations. In the left hand side of $$e^x - \left(1 + x + \cdots + \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right) = \int_0^x \frac{e^t}{(k-1)!}(x-t)^{k-1} \, dt $$ why do we expand until $k-1$? Also, how do we go from the left to the right hand side? Could you please provide some details or a reference?

Comment: @Thoth: It is Taylor's theorem with the integral remainder $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}  \frac{x^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(0) + \int_0^x \frac{f^{k}(t)}{(k-1)!} (x-t)^{k-1} \, dt $$ for the function $f(x) =e^x$ and $a=0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder.

Comment: Thanks. Please let me ask something that I can not understand. In the quoted part of your answer, you mention that the equality holds for any $f_k$ that is strictly increasing. I am trying to understand the rationale for making this generalization as $f_k$ has a strict definition below. Could you please provide some intuition or analytical description?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to explain why $f_k(x)$ is an increasing function?

Comment: @Thoth: Because the integrand $e^{xu} (1-u)^{k-1} $ is a strictly increasing function of $x$ for every $u \in [0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Express $f(x)= \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ as a triple integral
$$f(x)=\int_0^x \int_0^t \int_0^s \frac{ue^u}{t^3}dudsdt>0
$$