# Given $\phi(u) = e^u-u-1$ why $\phi(tx)\leq x^2\phi(t)$ for $x<1$ and $t>0$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

I am reading a proof where an auxiliary function $$\phi(u) = e^u-u-1$$ is used. At some point it is stated that the function $u \mapsto \frac{\phi(u)}{u^2} $ is increasing and given $x<1$ we "obviously" have

$$\phi(tx)\leq  x^2\phi(t)$$ where $t>0$. Could you please someone explain anlyticaly why this is true? Also, in the more general case where $x < b$ and $b>0$ can we use the same inequality? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if it should be $\phi(tx)\leq  x^2\phi(t)$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes it is, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $u > 0$ is
$$
 \phi(u) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k!} = u^2 f(u)
$$
with an increasing function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, see for example

- [Prove that the function $\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ is increasing.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061846/prove-that-the-function-fracex-1-xx2-is-increasing).

For $t > 0$ and $x < 1$ is $tx < t$ and therefore
$$
 \phi(tx) = t^2 x^2 f(tx) \le t^2 x^2 f(t) = x^2 \phi(t) \, .
$$

For $t > 0$ and $x < b$ with $b > 0$ the estimate would be
$$
 \phi(tx) = t^2 x^2 f(tx) \le t^2 x^2 f(tb) = \left(\frac xb\right)^2 \phi(tb) \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have two questions. First how $\phi(u) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k!} = u^2 f(u)$ can be shown and secondly in the first bullet why $tx<x$? Did you assume that $t<1$ or dit you assume $x<1$ and you meant $tx<t$?

Comment: @Thoth: Sorry, what was a typo, it should $tx < t$. – For your other question see the linked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061846/prove-that-the-function-fracex-1-xx2-is-increasing (to which I added another answer).

Comment: In the link, it is show that $f(x)= \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ is increasing. I do not see the relation $\phi(u) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k!} = u^2 f(u)$. Is an implicit outcome of some answer? Cloud you please be more specific?

Comment: @Thoth: $\phi(u) = e^u-1-u = u^2 f(u)$ and $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Yes there is something I need to verify if it is possible. The second part also works for $b>1$?

Comment: @Thoth: Yes....